# Select records where I select the latest rows from a group based on a date in mysql?

Tags: sql, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the next records from the table 'data'

| date_post | date_complete |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-11-28 | 2023-12-04 |
| 2023-11-28 | 2023-12-04 |
| 2023-11-28 | 2023-12-05 |
| 2023-11-28 | 2023-12-05 |
| 2023-11-29 | 2023-12-06 |
| 2023-11-29 | 2023-12-06 |
| 2023-11-29 | 2023-12-07 |
| 2023-11-29 | 2023-12-07 |

it's posible to select something like this?

| date_post | date_complete |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-11-28 | 2023-12-05 |
| 2023-11-28 | 2023-12-05 |
| 2023-11-29 | 2023-12-07 |
| 2023-11-29 | 2023-12-07 |

select the latest rows from date_complete but where the selection was in all the rows that have the same date_post
thanks.

I not really good at mysql so I was asking if this is posible

Answer (score 2):

You can use subquery to select the latest values and later fetch details from that.

```sql
SELECT date_post, date_complete
FROM
    data
JOIN (
    SELECT
        date_post,
        MAX(date_complete) AS latest_date_complete
    FROM
        data
    GROUP BY
        date_post
) AS max_dates
ON
    date_post = max_dates.date_post
    AND d.date_complete = max_dates.latest_date_complete;
```

If you are seeking just to find latest date_complete for each unique date_post value you can use the MAX function to find the maximum date_complete within each group created by the GROUP BY clause as follow.

```sql
SELECT
    date_post,
    MAX(date_complete) AS latest_date_complete
FROM
    data
GROUP BY
    date_post;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use aggregation here:

```
SELECT d.date_post, d.date_complete
FROM data d
JOIN (
    SELECT date_post, MAX(date_complete) AS max_date_complete
    FROM data
    GROUP BY date_post
) AS sub
ON d.date_post = sub.date_post AND d.date_complete = sub.max_date_complete;
```

Here is [sample fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/75Q2q6as)

Answer (score 0):

You have also the option to use the window function `MAX()` to retrieve the highest date within a group defined by *date_post*. then, display only the rows that correspond to this maximum date :

```
SELECT date_post, date_complete
FROM (
    SELECT date_post, date_complete,
      MAX(date_complete) OVER (PARTITION BY date_post ORDER BY date_complete DESC) AS max_date_complete
    FROM `data`
) AS d
WHERE max_date_complete = date_complete;
```